# ARCore and Location Services

Tags: android, google-maps, location, arcore

I am wondering is there any options for combining existing *ARCore* early stage with Google Location in order to place AR objects over `latitude / longitude` in the real world? I know this one is possible with *ARKit* but haven't found any information on such via *ARCore*.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add more details to your question ?

Comment: Use Anchor class, it will handle itself

Comment: Did you find out any more about this?  I'm trying to do something similar but no luck so far. My understanding is that I need to call `session.createAnchor()` with a `Pose` object that in turn is created using translation/rotation info between user's current location and lat/long for object.

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly did you find any solution?

Comment: @IshRoid did you find any solution?

Comment: My above comment explained it already :-) @abhishek

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/aishnacodes/Geolocation-ARCore

Comment: Btw, currently it is much easier and really possible to perform things using https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A option that's recently emerged would be: https://www.appoly.co.uk/arcore-location/

It allows you to render objects at a GPS location. Currently it offers two example renderers - an annotation, or a 2D image - however you can implement your own custom ones based on the example code which shows 3D models.

It's worth noting that this is based around Android SDK and not Unity etc.

[image: Annotation example]

Comment: Worth to try! Thanks a lot for the finding.

Comment: Marked as accepted answer. This one worked fine at least as the starting point!

Comment: @Array so how it went? Did you achieve it successfully along with 3d object?

Comment: @HaiderSaleem it was a long time ago so far. I achieved it that time but cannot provide the solution so far :(

Comment: it seems it doesn't use `Geospatial` so accuracy may be very bad, because when I tested it outside a location marker was changing its position in different directions while I standing and holding the phone in the same position...

Comment: it doesn't really work like on that gif, it jumps from place to place

Answer (score 6):

I think that this is not 0/1 type question :)

First of all ARCore is SDK only for mapping the surrounding. It has no computer vision and/or location capabilities.

Your request is possible but you must combine two elements. First you need to work with location (GPS) and calculate that selected location lat/lng is in your view. This quite simple, you can find a lot of tutorials about that.

Than when you will be sure where this point is ( you can also calculate the bearing that will help here) you can use ARCore to pin the 3D model to the world. Probably you will have to make some kind of transformation to change the real world coordinates to your screen

Making the answer simpler: ARCore itself is not able to that, but combining different tools will allow you to achieve this goal

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do already have lat/lng for a lot of places I have, but cannot pin model to that location so it is visible through ARCore stuff (with lighting, VIO and so on). Would you be so kind and tell me about some tutorials allowing to point ARCore 3D model to the world coordinates? I've done something like this using pure OpenGL, but not with ARCore.

Comment: you won't find them yet. ARCore is still fresh and most of the things you need to figure it out by yourself You can search for this topic related with OpenGL on Adnroid. Math that is standing behind it is the same in both scenarios, the difference will be how to get proper objects and values but ARCore delivers a lot of things related with matrix for example

Comment: Please let me know If anyone knows how to achieve it as in ArCore, The markers are not stable. i have searched a lot but did not get anything except    https://www.appoly.co.uk/arcore-location/. But this too is not stable. Please let me know if you found any solution for Geolocationservice + ArCore.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this and was thinking about how great this would be. So try to think how like Pokemon Go did.

My suggestions is:

Tracking user location by GPS, when it get in the right lat/lng (don't use one point, but a radio/area) you sent the place of the object/anchor using the user as 0,0 (origin). So will not be perfect, but is a start for this.

And yes, is **possible**, take a look on [World Around Me App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.WTInfoTech.WorldAroundMeLite)

Answer (score 0):

i am also creating similar app. In my case i want to display video at specific longitude and latitude, I achieved it using geo-fencing. I select a specific point and set radius around it  approximately 20m. when i enter in the radius my app start showing video in that area.

Answer (score 0):

#### ARCore 1.31 is capable of generating and tracking Geospatial Anchors

Google ARCore 1.31+ enables your app for global-scale location-based AR experience. Its Geospatial API helps you collect geospatial model's data from Google Earth 3D and Street View images – there are billions of panoramic street images provided by Google VPS. Street View’s content comes from two sources - Google (that uses Street View cars with LiDARs) and private contributors (that use Street View trekker).

To use ARCore Geospatial API, you need a [supported device](https://developers.google.com/ar/devices), supported area, and fast internet connection.

Comment: How can we just show a simple view of Location Marker instead of using OpenGL?

Comment: Hey @user924, post it as SO question.

Answer (score -3):

I use mapbox, with arcore, you just have to do the "magic" ( when nearby location, transition to ar core scene, and put GO at approximate location ) 
I used player position, and orientation, than it lays out the level in front of the player, at the feet, with a raycast to the ground, It will only spawn if the ray actally hit a plane(tracked plane), making sure its on the tracked plane